# Bridge API (Bankin) on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, open-banking

I'm connecting to my first API and I do not know where to start.
I have tried a few things but it doesn't work.
Have you ever connected bankin api on a Ruby on Rails app?

I only have access to curl documentation but don't know how to "convert" it to Rails:

```
curl 'https://sync.bankin.com/v2/users' \
    -X POST \
    -H 'Bankin-Version: 2019-02-18' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Client-Id: MY_CLIENT_ID' \
    -H 'Client-Secret: MY_CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -d $'{
           "email": "john.doe@email.com",
           "password": "password123"
         }'
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

try https://api.tilisy.com instead. there are Ruby code samples: https://github.com/enablebanking/tilisy-api-samples/blob/master/ruby_example/lib/main.rb

Comment: i ll read the documentation and try it, but the API does not provide data from french institutions so I won't have the use for it

Comment: @LDC now api.tilisy.com also supports majority of french institutions.